# Use of 'ClickAt ' selenium command

Tags: selenium

I'm confused about the difference between the `Click` and `ClickAt` commands in selenium. Where can I use the `ClickAt` command?

Answer (score 13):

Here are what Selenium IDE says about those two commands :

> **`click(locator)`** 
> Arguments:
>
> - locator : an element locator
>
> Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or
>   radio button. If the click action
>   causes a new page to load (like a link
>   usually does), call waitForPageToLoad.

And :

> **`clickAt(locator, coordString)`** 
> Arguments:
>
> - locator : an element locator
> - coordString : specifies the x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) of the mouse
>     event relative to the element returned
>     by the locator.
>
> Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or
>   radio button. If the click action
>   causes a new page to load (like a link
>   usually does), call waitForPageToLoad.

`click` is used when you just want to "click" on an element, like a button, a link, ...

And `clickAt` is used when you want to "click" on a **position designated by mouse coordinates**.

I suppose the second one can be useful for some "rich" applications -- I've actually never used it... On the other hand, I use `click` like all the time.

If you have a page with form elements, links, buttons, and stuff like that, you'll probably generally use `click` : it's way easier to find an element using it's id or classname than having to find it's position in pixels on the page ^^

Answer (score 3):

I noticed some differences between click() and clickAt() when testing a ExtJS app.
For example, if I try to *click* a tab in a *Ext.TabPanel*, click() command does not work, although I provide it with an correct xpath, and clickAt() works fine. 
Code looks like this:

```
click("//li[@id='tab-panel-id__second-tab-id']/a[2]/em/span/span")
```

doesn't work, but

```
clickAt("//li[@id='tab-panel-id__second-tab-id']/a[2]/em/span/span","0,0")
```

works.
Notice that coordinates are (0,0)

I can't figure out why this happens...

Comment: +1. I have the same problem with a Senchatouch app, and using click_at solved the problems

Comment: That's correct. The interesting thing is that ClickAt also works without the coordinates.
This is quite significant because selecting items from "chozen" dropdowns only works with ClickAt but not with Click!

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing a GWT application and it seems like I have to use clickAt if I want to click on a node in a tree widget.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when testing clickAt. Sometimes double clicking the command will cause it to show up red. You will change the line to try other alternatives but nothing will work. But then run your script and the clickAt line will be fine with whatever you type in.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dojo widget at our application which only works with `clickAt("//span[@id='mastheadIconBar']/span[1]/span/span","0,0")`.

Don't know why, but only `click("//span[@id='mastheadIconBar']/span[1]/span/span")` does not work.