# Selecting an element in Jquery based on an absolute position?

Tags: jquery, selenium

I use Selenium Webdriver for testing and want to test the creation of a new time slot in the calendar. As a calendar I use the Jquery week calendar:
https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar
The challenge is, that the calendar has only a DOM element per day (the column) and not per time slot (the rows). The jquery plugin calculates based on the absolute position of the click the corresponding time slot.
So, how can I simulate this in Selenium? I would need something like

```
page.execute_script("$('absolute position').trigger('click')")
```

But the Jquery functions offset and position only work for existing elements, not to find an element. Is there any possibility?

Comment: hey, have you tried this - some good answers here - (hope this helps) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340171/use-of-clickat-selenium-comand ; and +1 for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a candidate-collection of elements - maybe based on a class all the elements have or on position in the DOM.
The do a loop over all of them, test the position of each element - and click only if you found your target.

```
$('#day5 .item').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.position().top < 400) {
        $this.click();
    }
});
```