# Popup window not showing on clicking button in Selenium RC in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, popup, selenium-rc

Selenium RC does not opens the popup window on clicking on it.
When I click on the button manually, the popup is shown.

The HTML for the code looks like:

```
< button name="btndm" class="btnLrg" onclick="window.status=''; popUp3('reports/Datamart_reports.cfm?AutoChooseRpt=mdh000')" type="button">
```

I am using:

```
selenium.clickAt("name=btndm", "45000");
```

but the popup does not show.

Browser: IE

This project is IE specific so cannot try with any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use clickAt() method correctly, this post will explain you the difference between click() and clickAt():
[Use of 'ClickAt ' selenium command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340171/use-of-clickat-selenium-command)